# Objective C NSLock: lock and unlock a NSLock on different threads

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, macos, thread-safety

I need to set a mutex before to make an asynchronous request, and then unlock the mutex in the callback of this request that is on another thread.

Apple documentation say:

> Warning: The NSLock class uses POSIX
>   threads to implement its locking
>   behavior. When sending an unlock
>   message to an NSLock object, you must
>   be sure that message is sent from the
>   same thread that sent the initial lock
>   message. Unlocking a lock from a
>   different thread can result in
>   undefined behavior.

How can I avoid this "undefined behaviour" and make it work as expected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better yet;  use an `NSOperationQueue` or a GCD queue as your synchronization primitive.

Locks are expensive and semaphores are, more or less, a lock with a counter.

Queue based coding is far more efficient, especially when using the built in queuing mechanisms.

Comment: So, in this case you suggest to use a NSOperationQueue with  maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1? In this case only one operation is executed, and it's not possible to have race condition

Answer (score 5):

Use a `NSCondition` for this to signal other threads that they can safely pass now.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a mutex for this.  Use a semaphore initialized to 1 or some other lock mechanism that allows cross-thread communication/locking.

Rgds,
Martin